# How to set value to an Usercontrol inside a ListBox Item Template while loading listbox?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, listbox, itemtemplate

I have an `UserControl` and inside that there is a `DependencyProperty` `EmployeeSchedule` which will accept a `DataTable` or a `DataRow`. I created a `Listbox` and in the `ItemTemplate` I referred to this `UserControl`.

My question is that the data for the `UserControl` is the currentrow or `DataContext` of the `ListboxItem` which it is placed. How will I supply data of the `ListboxItem` to the user controls dependency property?

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<custom:MyUserControl EmployeeSchedule="{Binding PathToScheduleOffTheAcutalDataObject}" />
```

surely? Data Binding provides a powerful way for you to refer to properties that are available on your data item. This can take forms such as the simple property name, to multi-level paths, as well as array indexes.